# Field modes and canonical quantization in Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, vacuum, qft-in-curved-spacetime

A scalar field can be quantized as $\phi(x) = \sum_k (\hat{a}_k u_k + \hat{a}^\dagger_k u_k^*)$, where $u_k$ are positive frequency modes satisfying the Klein-Gordon (K-G) equation $(\Box +m^2)u_k = 0.$ There are in general multiple solutions to the K-G equation which may give inequivalent basis modes $u_k$ each leading to a different vacuum state.

My question is how do we get the modes for different vacua in Schwarzschild spacetime. For example, I know that Boulware modes can be obtained by solving the K-G equation using Schwarzschild coordinates with the coordinate time $t$ defining positive frequency. However, I have not been able to find an explicit form of the mode function for the Unruh vacuum. Can anyone guide me on how to proceed or any reference which gives an explicit form of $u_k$s for the Unruh vacuum?

Comment: See the text by Birrell/Davies for starters, Chapter 8. Unruh vacuum is made "artificially" by replacing half of Hartle-Hawking modes with Boulware one, motivated by ray-tracing arguments in order to simulate purely outgoing radiation flux.